# Doubt about the sufficient condition for differentiability with a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the sufficient condition for differentiability that is:

> If a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ has partial derivatives in a
>   neighborhood $D$ of $(x_0,y_0)$, and if these are continuous at
>   $(x_0,y_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$

because if I have the function: $f(x,y) =   \begin{cases} x(y-1) \sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) &\text{if $x) \neq 0$ }\\y^2-y&\text{if $ x=0$}\end{cases}$

First, it's continuous at the point $(0,1)$ because

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_{0})}f(x,y)$$ with $y=y_{0}$ is $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,y_{0})=0$$  and $y_{0}^2-y_{0}=0$ iff $y_{0}=0$ or $y_{0}=1$ then $f$ can't be continuous at the points $(0,y_{0})$ with $y_{0} \ne 0$ or $y_{0} \ne 1$lso I demonstrated this limit by definition of limit and effectively  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_{0})}f(x,y)=0$$

Second $f$ has partial derivatives continuous at the point $(0,1)$:

$$\frac{\partial f(0,1)}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(h,1)-f(0,1)}{h}=0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f(0,1)}{\partial y}=\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(0,k+1)-f(0,1)}{h}=1$$

So by the sufficient condition for differentiable I understand that $f$ is differentiable at the point (0,1). But when I checked for differentiability using the definition, the limit that should be $0$ doesn't exist. The following limit has to be $0$ if the function is differentiable at that point $(0,1)$

$$\lim_{x,y\to(0,1)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,1)-\frac{\partial f(0,1)}{\partial x}x-\frac{\partial f(0,1)}{\partial y }(y-1)}{\|(x,y)-(0,1)\|}$$

This limit doesn't exist so $f$ isn't differentiable at $(0,1)$.

So I don't know if I'm making something wrong or I don't understand the sufficient condition for differentiability.

Comment: What's the limit for (x_0, 1) when x_0 -> 0?

Comment: I analyzed the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_{0})}f(x,y)$$ using $y=y_0$. When I approaching the function by that way I obtained  0 as a candidate a for that limit. Then, I showed that this limit is zero by definition of limit (I didn't transcribe that demostration in this post)